# How to convert flat mesh into a slab while preserving shape?

Tags: blender, mesh, meshlab

This may be a very basic and dumb question but regardless I cannot get it to work.

I have a 3D file (STL format) that is flat and not closed. How can I give it some height (ie. convert it into a slab) but still preserve the curvature/shape on one of the sides?

Answer (score 0):

**solidify modifier** is meant for that: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html

It will add thickness to the object.